# Is there any need to index b again as it is already a under primary

Tags: mysql, indexing

Is there any need to index b again as it is already a  under primary-
if **primary(a,b)**  and in query we have `where b=' ';`

Is there any need to **index(b)** again individually because while indexing it will take left column first then thinks of the next.

Comment: if `b` is a primary key then no need to create index on `b`

Comment: please have a look at below @akhilesh
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66790/is-there-any-need-to-index-b-again-as-it-is-already-a-under-primary/66791#66791

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is since the order matters - with B-Tree based indexes you can only optimize left most lookups.

So if you are going to perform `WHERE b = CONST` searches and want to avoid fullscans - you have to create an index that covers `b` as its left most part.